# Preventing g++ From Terminating After First Compilation Error

Tags: c++, gcc, g++

I just installed the newest version of g++ (4.8.1) and whenever I try to compile a file that has compilation errors, it only displays the first instance of an error and then terminates. Basically, if the file has 3 compilation errors, g++ will only display the first error and then say "compilation terminated" without displaying the other two errors. In previous versions, g++ would display all the compilation errors. Is there a way to force this version of g++ to print out all the compilation errors or is this just how the new g++ works? I have the newest version of gcc installed as well and it also seems to have the same problem.

Comment: Did you looked at the compilations flags available ?

Comment: man _-Wfatal-errors_ flag

Comment: I have several different flags to try and get it to produce the errors. I've tried -Werror, -fmax-errors=5, and various other flags but it still does the same thing. It almost appears as if g++ is automatically using this flag: -Wfatal-errors (This option causes the compiler to abort compilation on the first error occurred rather than trying to keep going and printing further error messages) buit i'm not using it anywhere in my compile command. I've simply been using g++ filename

Comment: The problem is that after one error, the following ones might be spurious. I prefer bailing out at the first error.

Comment: In this case, I'm trying to get it to print out all the errors so I can log them and parse through them and count how many times each one occurs.

Comment: For such questions, show a testcase including compilation command.